# How do I create a string[] from "many" "independent" "strings"?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string

I have some strings defined `"a" "b"` and `"c"`.

How do I turn them into a string[] in  C#?

when I do `args = new string[3](file, DestUri, DestStorage);` I get "method name required"

Comment: `string[] arr = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create an array of strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088622/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Am I missing something or do you just need this:

```
string[] strings = new string[]{file, DestUri, DestStorage};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var a = "a";
var b = "b";
var c = "c";
var array = new [] { a, b, c };
```

or just

```
var array = new [] { "a", "b", "c" };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to declare a single dimension array which can be declared as follows:

string[] alphabet = new string[] {"a", "b", "c"};

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The most compact way:

```
string[] array = {"a", "b", "c"};
```