# How to initialize char** inside a struct

Tags: c, ansi-c

I have a struct

```
struct cmd{

  char **tokenized_cmd;
  int num_params;
}
```

at some point i need to initialize tokenized_cmd and pass values from another array into it

how to do that?

Comment: It depends what you want to initialise it to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088622/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-strings-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *arr[] = {"one", "two"};

struct cmd {
    char **tokenized_cmd;
    int num_params;
} x = {arr, 2};

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < x.num_params; i++)
        printf("%s\n", x.tokenized_cmd[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct cmd {
    char **tokenized_cmd;
    int num_params;
};

int main(void)
{
    char *arr[] = {"one", "two"};
    struct cmd x = {arr, 2};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < x.num_params; i++)
        printf("%s\n", x.tokenized_cmd[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

or the more flexible:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct cmd {
    char **tokenized_cmd;
    int num_params;
};

struct cmd *cmd_init(char **token, int params)
{
    struct cmd *x = malloc(sizeof *x);

    if (x == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    x->tokenized_cmd = token;
    x->num_params = params;
    return x;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *arr[] = {"one", "two"};
    struct cmd *x = cmd_init(arr, 2);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < x->num_params; i++)
        printf("%s\n", x->tokenized_cmd[i]);
    free(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: these options dont pass compilation

Comment: @LenaBru, are you sure? compiles for me without warnings using `-pedantic -Wall -W -Wextra`

Comment: @LenaBru  No problems compiling and running these examples.