# Initialize vector of string values

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to create an array of strings, which is inside of a structure, and I'm having a bit trouble on the syntax part. This is my code:

```
typedef struct data_players {
    int id;
    int hp; //start = 20, Max = 30
    int wght; // Max = 20
    int atk;
    int def;
    char *inventory[20] = {
        inventory[0] = "knife";
        inventory[1] = "healthpack";
    }
} jogador;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26221073/how-do-i-define-and-initialize-an-array-of-strings-inside-of-a-struct

Comment: Don't think it solves the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign inside `struct` definitions, nor are `typedef`s intended for *instances*; they are aliases for *types*.
With something like:

```
typedef struct data_players
{
    int id;     
    int hp; //start = 20, Max = 30
    int wght; // Max = 20
    int atk;
    int def;
    char *inventory[20];
} data_players;
```

You can then do:

```
data_players jogador = {0, 20, 15, 5, 5, {"knife", "healthpack", /* ... */}};
```

With a *designated initializer*, you can do:

```
data_players jogador = {.inventory = {"knife", "healthpack", /* ... */}};
```

Comment: Just one thing, if instead of one player I got, an array of players, will player[i] = {.inventory = {"knife", "healthpack", /* ... */}}; work?