# Printing a number into words. I have written this program. But I am getting segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This code is giving segmentation error some one please help me in finding the error.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char *single_numbers[10] =
    {
        "","one","two","three","four","five"
        ,"six","seven","eight","nine"
    };
    char *tens_numbers[8] =
    {
        "twenty","thirty","fourty","fifty"
        ,"sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"
    };
    char *teens[9] =
    {
        "eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen"
        ,"fifteen","sixteen","seventeen"
        ,"ëighteen","nineteen"
    };
    int number,thousands,hundreds,tens,units,temp;
    printf("enter the number");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    thousands=number/1000;
    hundreds=(number%1000)/100;
    temp=(number%100);
    tens=temp/10;
    units=number%10;
    if(temp>=20)
        printf("%sthousand %shundred %s%s"
            ,*single_numbers[thousands]
            ,*single_numbers[hundreds]
            ,*tens_numbers[tens - 2]
            ,*single_numbers[units]);
    else
        printf("%sthousand %shundred %s"
            ,*single_numbers[thousands]
            ,*single_numbers[hundreds]
            ,*teens[temp - 10]);
}
```

Comment: Please try to format your code so that it's a little more readable.

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org), that can help you find your segfault.

Comment: What happened to `"ten"`?

Comment: Listen to your compiler, he is your friend. With warnings enabled, you would have been able to see the problem by yourself.

Comment: [forty vs. fourty](http://grammarist.com/spelling/forty-fourty/)?

Answer (score 2):

Don't dereference `single_numbers[thousands]` and so on. These are already `char*`, if you dereference them, you make them `char`, but `printf` expects `char*`, so it defererences a given `char`, which leads to a segfault.

Comment: but how can I declare an array of strings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088622/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-strings-in-c

Comment: const char *a[2] = {"blah", "hmm"}; this one is given as a legal declaration. So whatever I have written must be legal.right?