# C - Relative path with fopen()

Tags: c, arrays, file, io, fopen

Here's my question: I have some relative paths saved in a matrix of strings. Depending on the user choiche, I have to open a certain file. The problem is that, when I use the fopen function, the file pointer doesn't point to anything. Here's a sample of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_PATH 100

///Global matrix of strings, containing the paths used in fopen() function
char paths[MAX_PATH][3] = {{"c:\\Users\\ThisPc\\Desktop\\file1.txt"},
                           {"c:\\Users\\ThisPc\\Desktop\\file2.txt"},
                           {"c:\\Users\\ThisPc\\Desktop\\file3.txt"}};

int main(){
    ///Declaring and initializing the 3 file pointers to NULL
    FILE *filepntr1 = NULL;
    FILE *filepntr2 = NULL;
    FILE *filepntr3 = NULL;

    ///Opening the 3 files with the correct arrays
    filepntr1 = fopen(paths[1], "w");
    filepntr2 = fopen(paths[2], "w");
    filepntr3 = fopen(paths[3], "w");

    ///Typing something on the files opened, just to check if the files where really opened
    fprintf(filepntr1, "hello");
    fprintf(filepntr2, "hello");
    fprintf(filepntr3, "hello");

    ///Closing the files
    fclose(filepntr1);
    fclose(filepntr2);
    fclose(filepntr3);

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, the three files remain blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You declared an array of 100 strings which are 3 bytes long, each.

Comment: No man, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/1095006/5085985. Also, the compiler would have tell me that, I am initializing the matrix with longer strings than 3 characters. Thank you for responding!

Comment: char strs[NUMBER_OF_STRINGS][STRING_LENGTH+1];
100 strings, which can hold 3 bytes (including the terminating '\0')

Comment: The compiler probably didn't warn you because you're making an assignment of a char ** type to a char **, which is legal. Always compile with -Wall when something goes wrong.

Comment: No man, your declaration is wrong, and indices start at 0 in C

Comment: @Alexguitar and Ed.s Allright, the blunder is always hiding in the darkest corner of the room. You are right, sorry, my bad!

Comment: compiling with all warnings enabled would have told you the syntax problems in the code.   When #define'ing a numeric value, always wrap the value in parens to avoid text-replacement errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Main issue that you incorrectly create and populate array of paths, try this approach for example:

```
const char* paths[3] = {"c:\\Users\\ThisPc\\Desktop\\file1.txt",
                        "c:\\Users\\ThisPc\\Desktop\\file2.txt",
                        "c:\\Users\\ThisPc\\Desktop\\file3.txt"};
```

Second issue that array index starts from 0:

```
filepntr1 = fopen(paths[0], "w");
filepntr2 = fopen(paths[1], "w");
filepntr3 = fopen(paths[2], "w");
```

Comment: Second issue: yeah, I forgot to correct the indexes, but in the program I am actually writing the indexes are correct (they start from 0). My bad, sorry!                                                                                                             First issue: it worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You should check against failure all of `fopen`, `fprintf`, `fclose` (on failure, consider using `perror`). And you might want to call (sometimes) `fflush`.

Be sure to read the documentation of every function I am mentioning here.

BTW, you can generate some file path, e.g.

```
char path[384];
int i = somenumber();
snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "/some/path/data_%d.txt", i);
FILE *f = fopen(path, "r");
if (!f) { perror(path); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Comment: Thank you man, I solved the problem but I didn't know these methods. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to be declaring a two-dimensional array for your paths? It looks like you're passing your whole first row (three strings) to `fopen()`.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1095006/5085985

Comment: Yes I am, in the actual program I need some container for all the paths I am using, basically because they are a lot and I don't want to create lots and lots of variables just to insert them in fopen(). Thank you for responding!