# Is it possible to have multiple strings in a single dimensional array in ANSI C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, ansi-c

I know how to make string array using a two dimensional array but can I do something like this:

```
char array[];
array[1]="bob";
array[2]="cat";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create an array of strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088622/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-strings-in-c)

Comment: I've read that post but I'm not trying use a multi-dimensional array or pointers

Comment: You already do. Guess what `"bob"` is? If you do not want to, the answer is "no"! Think for yourself how that should work.

Comment: You could, whatever the point is,but you would have to either index each one, or keep a count of how many, so that you know whether the `'\0'` signifies the end of a string or the end of all the array.

Comment: You could store into a single-dimensional array, but I can't think of a useful way to do it without either hard-coding the strings or at least temporarily storing into an array of pointers. I mean, you could use `argv` to get strings from the command line, but that is an array of pointers, too.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but not the way you're trying to do it.

For example, you could do this:

```
char arr[] = "bob\0cat";
```

`arr` contains two strings, `"bob"` starting at `arr[0]` and `"cat"` starting at `arr[4]`. This isn't particularly convenient, since you have to traverse the array to find the strings, but it does use memory efficiently.

Each element of `arr` is a single `char`, so you can't store a string in each element, but you can store multiple strings consecutively.

There are other ways to store lists of strings. The most common is to define an array of `char*` pointers, with each pointer pointing to (the first character of) a string that's been allocated elsewhere. The `argv` parameter of `main` is the most common example of this approach.

In your example:

```
char array[];
```

This is invalid; if you want to define an array object, you have to specify the number of elements.

```
array[1]="bob";
array[2]="cat";
```

These assignments are both invalid. `array[1]` and `array[2]` are both single `char` objects. You can't assign a string to a single `char`. Actually the expression `"bob"` is implicitly converted to a `char*` pointer -- which you *still* can't assign to a `char` object.

If you defined your `array` as an array of `char*` pointers, those assignments would be valid, and in fact that's the usual way to represent a list of strings:

```
char *array[2];  /* an array of pointers */
array[0] = "bob";
array[1] = "cat";
```

The strings themselves are allocated outside the array; the array contains pointers to them. Each pointer actually points to a single `char` object, but we can use that pointer to access the entire string.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but you have to use an array of pointers:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    char *ar[]={"one","two","three"};//array of pointer
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",ar[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, possible only if you can imagine the memory as a raw contiguous unit and know exactly what you are doing.

for example,

lets consider a memory block of 25 bytes as below

```
00                        04 
+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+ 09
|    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+ 14
|    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+ 19
|    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+ 24
|    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+ 29
```

Lets consider my allocation was like this

```
void *p = malloc( 5 * 5 * sizeof( char ) );
```

I can access a row of size 5 with pure pointer arithmatic as

for instance lets say I'll copy a string in 3rd row

```
memcpy ( p+(5*3) , "Hello", 5 );
```

Only problem is maintaining this raw area is little too complicated than usual, besides there are advantages in usage.

Comment: oops, this copies the string into the 4th row because, in C, offsets start from 0, not 1

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about storing *pointers* to strings, then yes:

```
const char *strings[SIZE];
strings[0] = "bob";
strings[1] = "cat";
...
```

Note that we're only storing the *addresses* of the string literals `"bob"` and `"cat"` in the `strings` array; the contents of the string literals are stored somewhere else.

`strings` is declared as an array of `const char *` since attempting to modify the contents of a string literal leads to undefined behavior.

If you want to store the *contents* of multiple strings in a single 1-D array, then you'll need to concatenate them together, something like:

```
char dest[SIZE] = {0}; // want to make sure at least the first element is 0
strcat( dest, "bob" );
strcat( dest, "cat" );
```

after which `dest` contains the string `"bobcat"`, where `"bob"` starts at index 0 and `"cat"` starts at index 3.  Note that you *cannot* use the `=` operator to assign string contents; you must either use a library function like `strcat`, or you must assign each character individually, like

```
dest[0] = 'b';
dest[1] = 'o';
dest[2] = 'b';
...
```

If you want to keep track of where individual strings begin and end within that 1-D sequence, then you will need to add some sort of delimiter, like

```
strcat( dest, "bob" );
strcat( dest, "$" );
strcat( dest, "cat" );
```

giving you the string `"bob$cat"`; you could then use `strtok` or `strchr` to find individual strings in the list of strings.