# copy a string to a char array in a function

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

How do these both work? I would think the second one wouldn't work because when it is called here `copy_string(line, line1)` since it does not have a `&`. It also does not use a pointer in the function header `copy_string(char line[], char line1[])`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void manipulateStrings(char *line[], char line1[])
{

    strcpy (line, line1);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[3] = {0};
    char line1[80] = "hi";
    manipulateStrings(&line, line1);
    printf("line is %s \n", line);
    printf("line1 is %s \n", line1);
    return 0;
}
```

Surprised this one works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void copy_string(char line[], char line1[]) {

    strcpy (line, line1);
}

int main() {
    char line[3] = {0};
    char line1[80] = "hi";
    copy_string(line, line1);
    printf("line is %s \n", line);
    printf("line1 is %s \n", line1);
    return 0;

   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The second one is correct. The first is expecting an array of pointers as first argument (notice it is the same as the `argv` argument for `main`). Turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: Any idea why this didn't complain about it http://ideone.com/LkDDnr? I usually use this for quick code snippets.

Comment: because it only shows you the warnings when you have an error: http://ideone.com/sigKqx

Comment: @WeatherVane like this right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088622/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-strings-in-c/1095006#1095006

Comment: @BeyelerStudios thank you for showing me that trick with ideone.