# strcpy Crashes C Program

Tags: c, strcpy

Please tell me why strcpy fails.
Im trying to copy the value str1 into
one of the element of str2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char str1[]={"cat"}; //string
    char *str2[]={"mouse","dog"}; //array
    strcpy(str2[0],str1);       

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to write into a read-only hard coded memory. Don't do it. A good book about pointers will be a good idea. Any way those strings are literal strings Google is your best friend.

Comment: By the way *str2[] is not an Array, is an Array of Pointers.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088622/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-strings-in-c) for better understanding how to create an array of strings.

Comment: Thanks iRov and Michi

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char str1[]={"cat"}; //string
```

is wrong  in this context

`""` is a replacement for tedious `{'a','b'...'\0'}`.

Do either

```
char str1[]="cat";
```

or

```
char str1[]={'c','a','t','\0'};
```

Even then your code wouldn't work

```
strcpy(str2[0],str1);
```

> because you are trying to write into a read-only hard coded memory

as [[ @michi ]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4745612/michi) mentioned  in his comment.

But below would work

```
str2[0]=malloc(sizeof(str1)); // You allocate memory for str2[0];
strcpy(str2[0],str1); 
printf("str2[0] : %s\n",str2[0])
```

Also remember to free the allocated memory after use

```
free(str2[0]);
```

Comment: This helps the OPs problem?

Comment: @Michi : Updated. Guess the op need to be good with the terminology and sure they need a good book

Comment: thank you. 

Changing the declaration to str2[2][20] makes it editable.

I'm just wondering how to make str2 as parameter of a function and reference each element by index;