# How to put a string into an array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am having a hard time putting a string into an array.

The purpose of my program is to generate random strings. And I want those random strings generated to be placed on an array so I can access those strings again later.

```
char main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    char* rStr[9] = {0};

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        randomString(rStr, 8);    //This is the function that generates a 
                          //random string with 8 characters
        printf("%d---%s\n", i, rStr);
    }   
}
```

The above code will produce 7 randomly-generated strings with 8 characters. But my problem is I want every strings generated to be placed on an array so I can call them or display them again.

I have tried this below:

```
char main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    char* rStr[9] = {0};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        rStr[i] = randomString(rStr, 8);
        printf("%d---%s\n", i, rStr[i]);
    }   
}
```

but my program would just crash.

EDIT:

```
int randomNumber(int min, int max)     //This function is responsible for 
                                       //the randomness of the string
{
    max -= min;
    return (rand() % max) +min;
}

char randomString(char *str, int randomCharCount)
{
    const char *charSet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < randomCharCount; i++)
    {
        str[i] = charSet[randomNumber(0, 35)];
    }
}
```

Credits of the code to the tutorial right here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3l1TKWVKyAY&index=58&list=PL0170B6E7DD6D8810&fbclid=IwAR2qq87y9qKt4PKPSZrwoRF10j1V9NU9W055j3-1YBXNBU7YtFDMMa1mxMg

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3l1TKWVKyAY&index=58&list=PL0170B6E7DD6D8810&fbclid=IwAR2qq87y9qKt4PKPSZrwoRF10j1V9NU9W055j3-1YBXNBU7YtFDMMa1mxMg

Comment: The problem is not in the code you show, but in the code you *don't* show. What does `randomString` *really* do? What does it *return*? Please create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: `char* rStr[9] = {0}` creates an ***array of 9 pointers to char***, not an array of `char [9]`??  (and be very wary of learning how to code from youtube...)

Comment: Your `randomString` function is declared to return a single `char`. And in fact doesn't return anything at all. You also dereference the pointer being passed, which is not the correct type (you pass a pointer to a pointer to `char`, i.e. `char **`).

Comment: Unless you are coding for a *freestanding* embedded system without an Operating System your declaration for `main` is incorrect. For hosted systems, the proper declarations for `main` are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char **argv)` See: [C11 Standard §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup p1 (draft n1570)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has following problems

1. No `return` type for `main()`.
2. You have to declare **separate array** for saving `strings`.

Try the following code :-

```
char main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));

  char rStr[9] = {0};
  // sStr is where the rStr are saved .
  char sStr[50][9];  // max 50 rStr
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
  {
    randomString(rStr, 8);
    strcpy(sStr[i],rStr);
    printf("%d---%s\n", i, sStr[i]);
  }
 // some return value here.
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question and providing a code, anoopknr! This is a huge help for me. God bless!

Answer (score 0):

Think you're looking for `strcpy`.

Initialising and then "pushing" to the array:

```
char stringarray[MAX_NUMBER_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_SIZE]; 
strcpy(stringarray[0], "blah");
```

Also main should return an int see valid options below for main:

```
int main(void);
```

or:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
```

References:

[How do I create an array of strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088622/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-strings-in-c)

[What are the valid signatures for C's main() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function/)