# How do I properly use strcat for char array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, string-literals, strcat

I'm trying to concatenate another string onto arg[0].

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char* arg[] = {
        "Hello",
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL
    };

    strcat(arg[0], " World");

}
```

This returns abort trap.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to create a new character buffer big enough to hold `Hello` + your new string and then concatenate them into that new buffer.

Comment: not allocating enough space for the concatenation.

Comment: " World" have 6 (becarful you have space at the begining) character and "Hello" only 5 (Total = 11 character !).

Comment: More precisely, `arg[0]` can only hold 5 characters (not counting null terminator) and you are trying to stuff 11 characters into it.

Comment: @Gillespie The number of characters is not the issue. String literals are read-only, so writing any number of characters is an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with "char \*s" but not "char s\[\]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha)

Comment: Since string literals are read-only, is there a way to make it write as well? Are strings always read-only?

Comment: True, but she will encounter the same problem if she tries to concatenate something to `char str[] = "hello"` as well. I was trying not to delve too far into technicalities

Comment: Also refer to [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1088667/3476780

Comment: And more specifically : [How do I concatenate const/literal strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/how-do-i-concatenate-const-literal-strings-in-c)

Comment: It's almost always better to use strncat than strcat.  Also, you might read http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/checking-early.html for an exploration of what can go wrong when you reference undefined memory - it uses FORTRAN for its examples, but the same thing applies to C.

Comment: ...but don't blindly apply @dstromberg 's good advice to `strncpy()` over `strcpy()`, because `strncpy()` behaviour is not quite what you'd naively expect both before *and* after reaching the size limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to rewrite a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) with:

```
char* arg[] = { "Hello", ..... };    // "Hello" is a string literal, pointed to by "arg[0]".

strcat(arg[0], " World");       // Attempt to rewrite/modify a string literal.
```

which isn´t possible.

String literals are only available to read, but not to write. That´s what make them "literal".

---

If you wonder about why:

```
char* arg[] = { "Hello", ..... };
```

implies `"Hello"` as a string literal, You should read the answers to that question:

[What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s)

---

By the way, it would be even not possible (or at least get a segmentation fault at run-time) if you would do something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char a[] = "Hello";  // 6 for holding "Hello" (5) + "\0" (1). 

    strcat(a, " World");   

}
```

because the array `a` needs to have 12 characters for concatenating both strings and using `strcat(a, " World");` - `"Hello"` (5 characters) + `" World"` (6 characters) + `\0` (1 character) but it only has 6 characters for holding `"Hello"` + `\0`. There is no memory space added to the array automagically when using `strcat()`.

If you execute the program with these statements, you are writing beyond the bounds of the array which is [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) and this will get you probably prompt a Segmentation Fault error.

Comment: You mean the `\0` NUL Terminator, not `\n` new line here ;)  Also you don't *necessarily* get a SEGFAULT, after all we are having UB here.

Comment: @larkey yes, it was confusion. Thanks for the hint. I´ve edited it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the shortcomings of C strings is that you need to know how big they will be ahead of time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char arg[1024] = "Hello";
    strcat(arg, " World");
    printf("%s\n", arg);
}
```

In this case, the size of the concatenated string must be less than 1024 characters. This is why it is safer to use something like C++, where you have `std::string` to prevent these types of issues.

Comment: I think changing to a whole another language is a bit out of scope and C++ introduces so many other pitfalls and complexities.

Comment: C++ isn't exactly a "whole other language" though. The above snippet is valid C++. There's really no reason to use pure C in this day and age outside of the context of academia when you have much safer alternatives like Rust and C++.

Comment: it is valid but bad C, eg. it is missing `void` in the function declaration. And yes, C++ is a whole new language, if one disregards the factually wrong claims by Bjarne for once. There are quite a few differences and good reasons not to use some C++ features but rather improve C in details. If one would go safe, I'd neither choose C nor C++, but this question is tagged C, so the answers should be C.