# how can i assign a randomly generated integer to a string in C?

Tags: c, string, random, integer

i'm trying to make a slot machine type thing and i wanted to assign the randomly generated numbers to certain symbols like 1 = cherry, 2 = bell and so on so i could print out the results in symbol form at the end.

i tried putting the symbols as strings in an array and assigning the numbers to the elements in the array in each slot functions but it didn't work out... is there a way to do this?

here's the code i've written so far, minus the array attempts. any suggestions would be helpful! :D

**EDIT:** here's an example of what i've tried doing on one of the slots but it keeps saying i need a cast to assign the integer from a pointer (i've tried searching online but idk how to do this)

```
char * slotOne(int randOne, const char *symbols[]) 
{ 
    randOne = rand() % 4 + 1; 

    if (randOne = 1)
    {
        randOne = *symbols;
    }
    if (randOne = 2)
    {
        randOne = *(symbols+1);
    }
    if (randOne = 3)
    {
        randOne = *(symbols+2);
    }
    else
    {
        randOne = *(symbols+3);
    }
    return randOne; 

}
```

this is the part of my main function where i've tried declaring the string array:

```
int main() 
{ 
    int x, one, two, three;
    const char *symbols[4] = {"bell", "orange", "cherry", "horseshoe"};

    srand(time(NULL)); 

    one = slotOne(x);
    two = slotTwo(x);
    three = slotThree(x); 

    printf("%s - %s - %s\n", one, two, three); 

    //...

}
```

not sure if %s or %c is the right type too...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you create an [array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1088667/530160), and use the random number to index that array?

Comment: You don't need all three of functions `slotOne()`, `slotTwo()`, and `slotThree()` — any one of them suffices for all three.  Well, it is not clear why you pass an argument into the function; it is simply used as a local variable that is overwritten (ignoring the value passed).  You should probably use a single function: `static int slotNumber(void) { int value = rand() % 4 + 1; return value; }` (where the local variable isn't absolutely necessary, but it makes debugging easier — you can set a breakpoint on `return` to see what will be returned). You then call `one = slotNumber();` etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i should've said above but this is "homework" and we were supposed to use more than 3 functions in the code but thank you for your suggestions! i'll try using them after finishing this

Comment: @NickODell thanks! i'm a beginner so i'm not really sure what you mean by using the random number to index the array? the link to the thread of string arrays was very helpful though!

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i've posted it :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least these problems:

---

Code is assigning `=` when it should compare `==`.

```
// if (randOne = 1)
if (randOne == 1)
```

---

The last `if () { ... } else { ... }` will cause one of the 2 blocks to execute.  OP wants an  `if () { ... } else if () { ... } else { ... }` tree.

```
// Problem code
if (randOne = 3) {
    randOne = *(symbols+2);
} else {
    randOne = *(symbols+3);
}
```

Suggest

```
if (randOne == 1) {
    randOne = *symbols;
} else if (randOne == 2) {
    randOne = *(symbols+1);
} else if (randOne == 3) {
    randOne = *(symbols+2);
} else {
    randOne = *(symbols+3);
}
```

Also research `switch`.

```
switch (randOne) {
  case 1:
    randOne = *symbols;
    break;
  case 2:
    randOne = *(symbols+1);
    break;
  case 3:
    randOne = *(symbols+2);
    break;
  default:
    randOne = *(symbols+3);
    break;
}
```

Or consider a coded solution:

```
randOne = *(symbols+(randOne-1));
```

---

But code needs to return a pointer to a *string* not an `int` and has no need to pass in `randOne` as a parameter.

```
const char * slotOne(const char *symbols[]) { 
    int randOne = rand() % 4; 
    return symbols[randOne];
}
```

Calling code also needs to adjust to receive a `const char *`, not an `int`.

```
// int one;
// one = slotOne(x);
const char *one = slotOne(symbols);
```