# Is it possible to create an array of strings in the same way as one can create an array of integers?

Tags: arrays, c, cs50, c-strings, undeclared-identifier

I'm trying to create an array of strings, by doing the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

string words[] = {apple, bear, card, duck};

int main(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", words[i]);
    }
}
```

I thought this was one of the ways that one could create an array, but when I try to compile, I get the error `error: use of undeclared identifier` for `apple`, `bear`, `card` and `duck`. However, when I try the same thing with integers:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

int main(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%i", numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

it compiles and runs without a hitch. Is it simply not possible to create an array of strings using this method, or is there something else I have missed? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1088667 this might help

Comment: `apple` is not a string. It's an identifier, like e.g. the name of a variable. `"apple"` (note the quotes) is a string literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strings must be quoted with `"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

const char *words[] = {"apple", "bear", "card", "duck"};

int main(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", words[i]);
    }
}
```